# Unexpected XML declaration. White Space not allowed

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net. I am generating a XML and Binding it to a treeview. Here is my code part..

```
sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
sb.Append("<astreeview xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>");
sb.Append("<astreeview-nodes>");
...........................
```

In my local machine its working fine and also i had deployed in 2 different servers. In one server, i am getting the treeview correctly. But in another server, i am getting the error like..

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 12285.

Same code is used in both the servers. What might be the issue here...

Comment: change your sb.append to appendline, so that you'll have a better way of deciding what part of the XML is causing the problem.  Line 1 position 12285 might be tough to look for.  Additionally, consider using xml serialization instead of writing out the XML by hand like you are above, but that is more of a long-term thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have some white space or other characters in that string

Remove it..

Clear the string builder and then appendLine it

```
sb.Clear();
sb.AppendLine("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
```

Comment: sb.clear(); gives me a clear error. Now i am all set..Thanks a lot for your help....

Comment: I am also bit confused with this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200572/restrict-specific-control-not-to-post-to-server.....Need suggestions